# JavaScript, DOM, creating dynamic events

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```html
<html>

<div id="menuID" style="visibility:hidden">
  <menuItems numItems="2">
    <items nname="Site Menu" numItems="3">
      <item>
        <mname>What's New</mname>
        <mvalue>http://yahoo.com</mvalue>
      </item>
      <item>
        <mname>What's Hot</mname>
        <mvalue>some URL</mvalue>
      </item>
      <item>
        <mname>Revised Scripts</mname>
        <mvalue>http://cnn.com/</mvalue>
      </item>
    </items>

    <items nname="FAQ Help" numItems="3">
      <item>
        <mname>Usage Terms</mname>
        <mvalue>some URL</mvalue>
      </item>
      <item>
        <mname>DHTML FAQs</mname>
        <mvalue>some URL</mvalue>
      </item>
      <item>
        <mname>Scripts FAQs</mname>
        <mvalue>some URL</mvalue>
      </item>
    </items>
  </menuItems>
</div>

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function parse() {
      var root = document.getElementById("menuID");
      for (i = 0; i < root.childNodes.length; i++)

        for (i = 0; i < root.childNodes.length; i++)
          if (root.childNodes[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'menuitems') {

            var aNode = root.childNodes[i];
            for (j = 0; j < aNode.childNodes.length; j++)
              if (aNode.childNodes[j].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'items') {
                var heading = document.createElement("div");
                root.appendChild(heading);
                heading.innerHTML = aNode.childNodes[j].getAttribute("nname");
                heading.style.visibility = "visible";
                heading.setAttribute('id', heading.innerHTML)
                //Create lists for each heading
                var uList = document.createElement("menu");
                uList.setAttribute('type', "list");
                heading.appendChild(uList);
                var uListID = heading.getAttribute('id') + j;
                uList.setAttribute('id', uListID);
                //document.write("ab " + uList.id + '<br>');
                uList.style.display = 'none';
                //uList.onmouseover = display(this.id);
                uList.setAttribute('onclick', 'display(this.id)');
                var bNode = aNode.childNodes[j];
                for (k = 0; k < bNode.childNodes.length; k++)
                  if (bNode.childNodes[k].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'item') {
                    var cNode = bNode.childNodes[k];
                    var list = document.createElement("li");
                    uList.appendChild(list);
                    var lnk = document.createElement("a");
                    for (l = 0; l < cNode.childNodes.length; l++) {
                      if (cNode.childNodes[l].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "mname") {
                        var hContent = cNode.childNodes[l].innerHTML;
                        lnk.innerHTML = hContent;
                      } else if (cNode.childNodes[l].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "mvalue") {
                        var hURL = cNode.childNodes[l].innerHTML;
                        lnk.setAttribute("href", hURL);
                      }
                    }
                    list.appendChild(lnk);
                  }
              }
          }

    }
  </script>

</head>

<body onLoad="parse();">
</body>


<script>
  function display(listID) {
    var thisList = document.getElementById(listID);
    if (thisList.style.display = 'none') {
      (thisList).style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
</script>

</html>
```

I'm working on a JavaScript / HTML project where I need to create a collapsible menu. The menu needs to be created dynamically using DOM walking. I have the script working to create the menu, but I'm having issues making it collapsible. I can't figure out how to dynamically pass the newly created ids of menu headings to the `onmousevent` attribute of each menu heading that is created.

I have tried:

```
uList.onmouseover = display(ulist.getAttribute('id0)); 
uList.setAttribute('onmouseclick', 'display(this.id)');
```

where `uList` is the tag being dynamically created and `display` is the function which determines wether the the menu is collapsed or not

```
function display(listID)
{
var thisList = listID;
if(thisList.style.display = 'none')
    ( 
        (thisList).style.display = 'block';
    )
}
```

The browser keeps giving me this error:

`Unable to set property 'display' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Devil's advocate perhaps, but: don't reinvent the wheel, use any of a number of already made UI libraries for this?

Comment: The body of `if` should be in `{}`, not `()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID, you need to call `getElementById()` to get the DOM element:

```
var thisList = getElementById(listID);
```

Alternatively, instead of passing the ID to the function, you can pass the element itself:

```
uList.setAttribute('onclick', 'display(this)');
```

Better would be to write it in more modern style:

```
ulist.addEventListener('click', function() {
    display(this);
});
```

Comment: Ok so when I change the code to uList.setAttribute('onClick', 'display(this)');  the browser stops throwing errors but when I click on the menu headers nothing happens

Comment: can you make a code snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: var uListID = heading.getAttribute('id') + j;
uList.setAttribute('id', uListID);
//document.write("ab " + uList.id + '<br>');
uList.style.display = 'none';
//uList.onmouseover = display(this.id);
uList.setAttribute('onclick', 'display(this.id)');

Comment: A code snippet is executable HTML and Javascript in the question.

Comment: Edit your question and click on the icon with the pencil to create a code snippet.

Comment: So I am new to this site...how can I add the snippet here

Comment: argh.. string callbacks!! What is this? The 90s?

Comment: You have the click handler on the hidden menu elements. Shouldn't it be on something that's not hidden, so that you can use it to show the menu?

Comment: oops...so I changed the code to say heading.setAttribute('onclick', 'display(this.id)').... in the display function say to hide/unhide heading first child... I tried: var thisList = document.getElementById(listID).firstChild

Comment: Use the Javascript debugger in the console to see what's being returned by these expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you make a mistake in `if` syntax, it's not using () but {}.

```
function display(listID)
{
var thisList = listID;
if($('#'+thisList).css('display') == 'none'){
        $('#'+thisList).css('display','block');
    }
}
```

Comment: that mistake was only in the way I wrote it on the site